# Client side routing not working in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Update: FIXED! I made a silly mistake because I had a [language]/folder and I forgot to provide the language in the href and query params.

I have the following pages;

- pages/_app.js
- pages/_document.js
- pages/index.js
- pages/order.js
- pages/discover/[categoryId].js

Here is the order page. The client side routing only changes the url but not the content of the page. If I refresh the page I get the last content. So the server side routing works but the client side routing only changes the url and not the content.

```js
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Order() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Orders</title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        <p>Put orders here</p>
        <Link href={"/"}>
          <a>Home</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href={"/discover/[categoryId]"} as={"/discover/0"}>
          <a>Orders</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Do I do something wrong or what could potentially cause this issue?

Next version: 9.5.0
React/React-dom: 16.13.1

Comment: It might be cached, have you tried to clean project and rebuild ?

Comment: try to use Router.push instead of Link

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this way. I am using next 9.2.1, and it works fine.

```
<Link href={{pathname: "/discover/[categoryId]", query: { categoryId: 0 }}} as={"/discover/0"}>
  <a>Orders</a>
</Link>
```